# Retrieving css color attribute using using Protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, karma-jasmine

I need to validate the color of a email link text . 
Below is my code:

```
it('Contact Text Validation', function(){

    expect (Contact_info_on_Login_screen.isDisplayed())


    var Email_Link = element(by.css("body > app-root > app-login > div > div > div > div > div > div.card-header.py-3.d-flex.justify-content-between.align-items-center > div > p > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)"));

    var Col_Email = (Email_Link.getCssValue('color')).then(function(){
        browser.sleep(2000).then(function(){

            console.log(" The color for Email Link is :" + Col_Email);
        });
    });

}
```

The color of the same element is as shown in the css property is as below.

[image]

the related html code is `<p _ngcontent-c1="" class="m-4"> Questions about filling in the report data or access to the application, please call <a _ngcontent-c1="" class="text-link-blue" href=""><span _ngcontent-c1="">Admin</span> / <span _ngcontent-c1=""> Manager</span></a> at <a _ngcontent-c1="" class="text-link-blue" href=""> 123-456-7890</a>. For software issues, email <a _ngcontent-c1="" class="text-link-blue" href="">other person</a> . </p>`

When I run this  , I got the following output from Protractor:

> [13:58:52] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
>   Started
>    The color for Email Link is :ManagedPromise::643 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. It should return the color code, instead it shows that the promise is pending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Email_Link.getCssValue('color').then(function (Value) {
    console.log("color is :" + Value);
});
```

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getCssValue

you can validate attributes by two ways.

```
expect(element(element(by.css("body > app-root > app-login > div > div > div > div > div > div.card-header.py-3.d-flex.justify-content-between.align-items-center > div > p > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)"))).getCssValue('color')).toBe('#000000');
```

or

```
            return Email_Link.getCssValue("color").then(function (value) 
                {               
                if (value[0]== "rgba(55, 199, 119, 1)") {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

You are incorrectly resolving a promise, the callback function receives the actual resolved value *as an argument*:

```
//                                             v-----HERE-----v
Email_Link.getCssValue('color').then(function (actualColorValue) {
    console.log("The color for Email Link is :" + actualColorValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Email_Link.getCssValue('color')).then(function(Col_Email){
  console.log(" The color for Email Link is :" + Col_Email);
};
```